# Validation of POJO with enum field

Tags: java, spring, validation, java-8

I am working with spring and spring validations for POJO.

Inside of POJO i have some of fields whose values will mapped to particular **`ENUM`** class.

As mentioned in below code, i have cardType field as **`CardType ENUM`**.

```
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.EqualsAndHashCode;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import lombok.experimental.SuperBuilder;
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.Length;

import javax.validation.constraints.Max;

@Data
@SuperBuilder(toBuilder = true)
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
class SamplePOJO {

    private String cardType;

    @Length(max = 20)
    private String name;

    @Max(10)
    private int number
}

public enum CardType {
VISA, MASTER;
}
```

For name and number i am able to do with **`@Max and @Length`**.
How can i apply validation for cardType that will belongs to mentioned **`enum`**.
Also in future, it may possible that i need to check with **`List`**  of values as well.
So if anyone can guide me.

Comment: @User-Upvotedon'tsayThanks , My field is not ENUM, it's string only.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A way is to write a custom annotation for enum validation. And use it on the field

```
@EnumNamePattern
private CardType cardType;
```

Custom Annotation

```
@Target({METHOD, FIELD, ANNOTATION_TYPE, CONSTRUCTOR, PARAMETER, TYPE_USE})
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy = EnumNamePatternValidator.class)
public @interface EnumNamePattern {
    String message() default "invalid";
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

Custom annotation validator

```
public class EnumNamePatternValidator implements ConstraintValidator<EnumNamePattern, String> {
    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        if (value == null) return true; 
        return Arrays.stream(CardType.values()).anyMatch(e -> e.name().equals(value));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you can create an annotation that checks if the String is valid for a specific enum.

```
@Target({METHOD, FIELD, ANNOTATION_TYPE, CONSTRUCTOR, PARAMETER, TYPE_USE})
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy = ValueOfEnumValidator.class)
public @interface ValueOfEnum {
    Class<? extends Enum<?>> enumClass();
    String message() default "must be any of enum {enumClass}";
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

Then you can add this annotation a String field and specify an enum class.

```
@ValueOfEnum(enumClass = CardType.class)
private String cardType;
```

Note: I found this on Baeldung [Validations for Enum Types](https://www.baeldung.com/javax-validations-enums).  There are examples of unit tests for this on that page as well.